# how many data should we choose for training and testing the neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am using MLP neural network. My question is for training the neural network and testing it how much splitting of data is needed like is there any rule that I always have to split data 70% for training and 30% for testing when I did this my accuracy was not good as when I split it into 10% for training and 90% for testing I got more accuracy... Is this valid?

Answer (score 1):

I am a little bit confused. How is possible that if you have 10%of data for training and 90% for testing is  less accurate than 30% for training and 70% for testing. From my experience of MLP ANN and my previous research this is not valid. In many papers I saw that most of researchers use half split for training and testing. I used various combinations. For example I used 9-fold cross valid where 2/9 are for train and 7/9 are for test. My opinion that % of train-test need to match segments (for example you have 15 subjects - samples from 10 subject use for train and samples from 5 use for test). There is no rule for splitting the data.

I hope that I helped you.

Comment: yea thank u..but I have more accuracy when I split it into 10% of data  for training and 90% of data for testing... and am comparing with (70% for training) and( 30 % for testing).

Answer (score 1):

How did you possibly get more accuracy while splitting the data in 1:9 ratio?

I generally use 70 percent for training and 30 percent for testing.

If the dataset is small, I use k-fold cross validation which brings out the best result possible